# Allow CI to run fastlane's download_dsyms action?

Tags: continuous-integration, fastlane, app-store-connect

I'm trying to run a scheduled workflow in CircleCI that would download my app's DSyms from iTunes/AppStore Connect and upload them to Firebase's Crashlytics, but `fastlane` asks for my Apple's password - and the build stalls:

```
[⠋]  [⠙]  [⠹]  [⠸]  [⠼]  [⠴]  [⠦]  [⠧]  [⠇]  [✔]  
[14:32:26]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[14:32:26]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[14:32:26]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[14:32:26]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[14:32:26]: ------------------------------
[14:32:26]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[14:32:26]: ------------------------------
[14:32:26]: Driving the lane 'ios dsyms' 
[14:32:26]: -----------------------------
[14:32:26]: --- Step: setup_circle_ci ---
[14:32:26]: -----------------------------
[14:32:26]: Creating temporary keychain: "fastlane_tmp_keychain".
[14:32:26]: Enabling match readonly mode.
[14:32:26]: -----------------------------------
[14:32:26]: --- Step: clean_build_artifacts ---
[14:32:26]: -----------------------------------
[14:32:26]: Cleaned up build artifacts 
[14:32:26]: ----------------------------
[14:32:26]: --- Step: download_dsyms ---
[14:32:26]: ----------------------------
[14:32:26]: Login to App Store Connect (MY_APPLE_ID)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please provide your Apple Developer Program account credentials
The login information you enter will be stored in your macOS Keychain
You can also pass the password using the `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` environment variable
See more information about it on GitHub: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/credentials_manager
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Password (for MY_APPLE_ID): **
```

I'm defining `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`, `FASTLANE_USER`, `MATCH_PASSWORD` and `PILOT_APPLE_ID` environment variables.

This is enough to run `upload_to_testflight(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)`, but can't make `download_dsyms` work.

My `.circleci/config.yml` (copied below) basically only runs `fastlane dsyms`, a lane defined like this:

```
  desc "Upload latest debug symbols to Crashlytics"
  lane :dsyms do
    clean_build_artifacts
    download_dsyms(version: 'latest')
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
    clean_build_artifacts
  end
```

My `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  dsyms:
    macos:
      xcode: "10.2.1"
    working_directory: /Users/distiller/project
    environment:
      FL_OUTPUT_DIR: output
      FASTLANE_LANE: dsyms
    shell: /bin/bash --login -o pipefail
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: 1-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - run: bundle check || bundle install --path vendor/bundle
      - save_cache:
          key: 1-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
      - run:
          name: fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE_LANE
      - store_artifacts:
          path: output

workflows:
  version: 2
  scheduled-workflow:
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "* 0 * * *"
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - testflight
    jobs:
      - dsyms
```

My (other lanes trimmed) `fastlane/Fastfile`:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end

  desc "Upload latest debug symbols to Crashlytics"
  lane :dsyms do
    clean_build_artifacts
    download_dsyms(version: 'latest')
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
    clean_build_artifacts
  end
end
```

**How can I make the CI download the DSyms from Apple?**

---

**EDIT**: if I add my password as a `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` environment variable, then the build still fails asking for the 2FA token.

```
[07:04:08]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[07:04:08]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[07:04:08]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[07:04:08]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[07:04:08]: ------------------------------
[07:04:08]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[07:04:08]: ------------------------------
[07:04:08]: Driving the lane 'ios dsyms' 
[07:04:08]: -----------------------------
[07:04:08]: --- Step: setup_circle_ci ---
[07:04:08]: -----------------------------
[07:04:08]: Creating temporary keychain: "fastlane_tmp_keychain".
[07:04:08]: Enabling match readonly mode.
[07:04:08]: -----------------------------------
[07:04:08]: --- Step: clean_build_artifacts ---
[07:04:08]: -----------------------------------
[07:04:08]: Cleaned up build artifacts 
[07:04:08]: ----------------------------
[07:04:08]: --- Step: download_dsyms ---
[07:04:08]: ----------------------------
[07:04:08]: Login to App Store Connect (xxxxxxxx@example.com)
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account 'xxxxxxxx@example.com'
More information about Two-factor Authentication: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

If you're running this in a non-interactive session (e.g. server or CI)
check out https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification

(Input `sms` to escape this prompt and select a trusted phone number to send the code as a text message)

(You can also set the environment variable `SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER` to automate this)
(Read more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Authentication.md#auto-select-sms-via-spaceship-2fa-sms-default-phone-number)

Please enter the 6 digit code:
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    Lane Context                                    |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                    |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                    |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios dsyms                                              |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/distiller/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+

+------+-----------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary              |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform      | 0           |
| 2    | setup_circle_ci       | 0           |
| 3    | clean_build_artifacts | 0           |
|    | download_dsyms        | 0           |
+------+-----------------------+-------------+

[07:04:09]: fastlane finished with errors
```

Answer (score 4):

Last Updated
App Store Connect API version **1.6** added support for fetching dSYM Urls. And
you now can use fastlane from version **2.197.0** to download dsyms via AppStore Connect API

```
app_store_connect_api_key(
  key_id: "D383SF739",
  issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
  key_filepath: "./AuthKey_D383SF739.p8"
)

download_dsyms(
  app_identifier: "com.joshdholtz.example"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define **FASTLANE_PASSWORD** Environment Variable. This is apple developer account password. Your App Store Connect / Apple Developer Portal password, usually needed if you also set the  FASTLANE_USER variable

**upload_to_testflight** - This uses FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD to upload binary to to App Store Connect

```
lane: refresh_dsyms do
  download_dsyms                           
end
```

This action downloads dSYM files from App Store Connect after the IPA gets re-compiled by Apple. This action requires **FASTLANE_PASSWORD**

Comment: But the `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` triggers a prompt for the 2FA token - which I cannot provide, since this is in the CI environment

Comment: You need to add FASTLANE_SESSION variable also with value which you get by runnning below command in terminal (user@email.com to be replaced with apple id).
fastlane spaceauth -u user@email.com